# Why my data is not saved using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have the following class

```
 public class Expense
{
    public Guid ExpenseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int cost { get; set; }
    public string extra { get; set; }
}
```

I am posting data from webpage to the cntroller method which saves this data in the database as follows:

```
   public string SaveExpense(Expense obj)
    {
        obj.ExpenseId = Guid.NewGuid();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.expenses.Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return "Saved";
        }
        else
            return "Error";   
    }
```

The Expense obj is posted from webpage using AJAX and JQuery. The data is coming into the controller method properly but it is not saved in the database. how can I save this data? Moreover, I am creating the ExpenseId while saving the data so records may be duplicates but will have the different ExpenseId. Please suggest me a way to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the changes you have made.

1. Try this: context.SaveChanges();

   From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx):

   > public int SaveChanges()
   >
   > //Persists all updates to the data source and resets change tracking in
   >   the object context.
2. Check the Return Value of the function to confirm if it was saved or not.

   > Type: System.Int32 The number of objects in an Added, Modified, or
   >   Deleted state when SaveChanges was called.
3. If it is not saved, then put the code inside a try-catch block and log the exception to check what is the problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @BhushanFirake modified my answer, try that and tell us what happened.

Comment: yes , it is returning 1 but i can't see the entry in the database

Comment: hey thanks...it is working now..got an entry in the databse..thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Call `SaveChanges()` on your `context` object to save your changes.